# How do I get GTK3 support in my existing python 3.7 install on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, gtk3, python-3.7

I have tried MSYS2 but that creates its own python environment and that will not work for me.
I tried Microsoft VCPKG but don't know how to export it (and I'm not using Visual Studio for development, however it is installed).

I managed to get cairo and pycairo installed
but when I run:
`python -m pip install --global-option="build_ext -IC:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include -LC:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib" --upgrade PyGObject`
it always errors out saying it can not find 'cairo.h' ('cairo.h' does exist)

https://pastebin.com/93buRzHg

I can see that my additional include directories are not being searched, and I don't know how else to add them.